# Can't Export runnable jar from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, runnable

i'm trying to export a runnable jar from eclipse, but this is the result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: neg1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: neg1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

This is the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ itextpdf-5.4.3.jar itext-pdfa-5.4.3.jar itext-xtra
 -5.4.3.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: Negozio.Start
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

And this is how the files are packed into the jar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXEaQ.png

Where Operazioni and Negozio are the my packages and the itext are the external library

Comment: have you already tried googling it? What methods have you already tried? If not, please start here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to include an external jar file?

Comment: I've flagged "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".

Answer (score 0):

You must have external jars that you did not include when you exported or were not put in your class path. Right click on your project **Properties->Java Build Path** and then ensure the "Libraries" tab is selected. Ensure the jars are added here.